# Bootstrap - can't align X and Y in the nav-bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have the nav-bar such that the name of the company is on the left with items X and Y on the right. I tried using justify-content-right as suggested in bootstrap documentation but it doesn't work.

```
<header>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top whitelight nav-masthead">
      <a class="navbar-brand gold-text font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Company Name</a>

      <!--Creates  a clickable button with a toggle icon once the screen collapses-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex flex-row" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-black"  style="font-size:16px; href="x.php">X <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-black" style="font-size:16px; href="y.php">Y<a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  <header>
```

Edit: I removed mr-auto class and that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close style attribute

```
<header>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top whitelight nav-masthead">
      <a class="navbar-brand gold-text font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Company Name</a>

      <!--Creates  a clickable button with a toggle icon once the screen collapses-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex flex-row" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-black"  style="font-size:16px"; href="x.php">X <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-black" style="font-size:16px"; href="y.php">Y<a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  <header>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, all it does is change the font. But my issue is aligning the items. Thanks though.

Comment: @github292929 can you add the css part of your code too

Comment: using bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: @github292929 to align your nav items from left to right add this to your css `.nav-item{float: left;}`

Comment: tried it doesn't work. I wonder why, because I even tried float: right. Edit: I removed mr-auto and that seemed to do the trick!